# Best way to assign value to lot of variables

Tags: esp8266, variables, array

I'm building web based remote control system for esp8266. In arduino IDE, using the ESP libraries. To, send data to the server, I'm using http post.
For some settings, I need to transfer 30 or so, different values over a single post request.  And assign it to different type of variables.

```
so, from this:
192.168.1.101/testpost?lenght=10&1=100&2=true&3=1800&4=125

i need this:

uint8_t brightness = 100;
bool randomOrder = true;
uint16_t Delay = 1800;
uint8_t Position = 125;
```

This is the relevant code. Basically, my idea is, to send the lenght of the array (will be different each time.) in the first argument.
Than create a for loop that put every value in a array into variable pointers. But, since lots of different type variables going on, i'm not sure how to do that.

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
#include <ESP8266mDNS.h>

//values i need to set in a single post.
uint8_t settings0;
bool brightness; 
uint16_t randomOrder; 
uint8_t Delay;

void setup {
//relevant code that handels post request.
server.on("/testpost", HTTP_POST, []() {

String ZeroValue = server.arg("lenght");

int lenght = ZeroValue.toInt();

//this doesnt really work, but its a starting idea.
int* SettingsArray[4] = {&settings0, &brightness, &randomOrder, &Delay};

for( int i = 0; i < lenght; i++) {

     String PresetSettings = server.arg(i);
     SettingsArray[i] = PresetSettings.toInt();
    }
});
}
```

Ultimately, I can just do that, but I'm wondering if there is a more elegant solution.

```
brightness = SettingsArray[1];
randomOrder = SettingsArray[2];
Delay = SettingsArray[3];
Position = SettingsArray[4];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WebServer class supports [argument lookup by name](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/libraries/ESP8266WebServer/src/ESP8266WebServer.h#L93). This should allow HTTP argument parsing that does not require length and/or specific order:

```
192.168.1.101/testpost?brightness=100&randomOrder=true&delay=1800&position=125
```

And parse with:

```
brightness = server.arg("brightness").toInt();
randomOrder = server.arg("randomOrder").toInt();
Delay = server.arg("delay").toInt();
Position = server.arg("position").toInt();
```

Please note that some value will require cast (and there might be a need for special handling of "true" and "false"). For further robustness each argument name needs to be checked that it is available.

```
String arg = server.arg("argName");
val = (arg.length() == 0 ? defaultVal : arg.toInt());
```

Or simply:

```
String arg = server.arg("argName");
if (arg.length() != 0) val = arg.toInt();
```

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you! didn't notice i can do that, that simplify code on front end as well.